# How can I set the indentation offset for `indent-region`

Tags: spacemacs, lsp-mode, ccls

I am using spacemacs + lsp layer (ccls) for c/c++ editing

Having my `c-basic-offset` set to 4:

- if I select a region and press `=` (maybe invoking `indent-region`?), the region is indented by 2 spaces (messages: `Applying [n] edits to [filename]`).
- If I press `=` without selecting a region, it indents with 4 spaces.

How can I control the indent level when indenting region?

Comment: Since you’re using lsp, it is probably using the language server to indent and not `indent-region`. Find out what command is run when you select a region and press `=` by first using `C-h k` and then hitting `=`.

Comment: Hi @scribe I didn't know the command `C-h k`. Thanks for letting me know helpful command. It turned out `evil-indent` was the function being invoked.

Comment: After investigating deeper, I found out `indent-region-function` was set to `lsp-format-region`. Now the question boils down to how I can change the behavior of `lsp-format-function`..

Comment: You can do `C-h v` to check the value of a variable as well. See what `indent-tabs-mode` is set to and what is `tab-width`. Setting those accordingly may help, read [this](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IndentationBasics) for more information on the two variables.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this'll work, but this is out of my configurations adjusted for what you want.

```lisp
(use-package cc-mode
  :init
  (defun my-c-mode-hook()
    (setq c-basic-offset 4
          c-label-offset 0
          tab-width 4
          indent-tabs-mode nil))
  (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
  (add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'lsp))
```